# How to show $e^{-x}$ is a cyclic vector for $-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ in $L^{2}[0,\infty)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}=L^{2}[0,\infty)$. How can one easily show that $e^{-x}$ is a cyclic vector under the $C^{\star}$ subalgebra of operators on $\mathcal{L}(H)$ generated by all resolvents $(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$ of the selfadjoint operator
$$
      Lf=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f
$$
whose domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consists of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f\in L^{2}[0,\infty)$ for which $f'' \in L^{2}[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=0$.

What does the cyclic representation look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can diagonalize $L$ (that is, make it a multiplication operator) with the help of the Fourier transform. More precisely, map $U:L^2(0,\infty)\to L^2(0,\infty)$, $Uf=\int f(x)\sin kx \, dx$; then $ULU^*$ is multiplication by $k^2$, and thus the cyclic vectors are exactly those for which $Uf\not=0$ almost everywhere. Clearly, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ has this property.

Comment: Thank you! And just for completeness would you mind quickly describing the map implementing the cyclic representation with respect to this cyclic vector?

Comment: I don't really understand that part of the question very well (not my home turf), but if I had to guess, then what you're looking for might be the map that sends $f(L)$ to  operator of multiplication by $f(k^2)$ on $L^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: It's a bit weird for me to unravel some of the $C^{\star}$ algebra details as well. That's why I'm asking. I'm thinking that the space ends up being $L^{2}_{w}(0,\infty)$ where $w=1/(1+k^{2})^{2}$ because of the $e^{-x}$. The state is, after normalization, $\Phi(A)=(Ae^{-x},e^{-x})$ where $A$ is in the $C^{\star}$ algebra generated by $(L-\lambda I)^{-1}$, $\lambda\in\rho(L)$.